# Sencha Touch: Reload NestedList and TreeStore after proxy URL change

Tags: sencha-touch

I have and application that uses NestedList with a TreeStore. TreeStore is using AJAX type proxy and XML reader. Now I have implemented Settings page, where you can change the URL that is used as a data source. Application needs to "reload" after that change. As a result, I change proxy URL:

`App.tree_store.proxy.url = new_url;`

Then I would like to load a new data:

```
App.tree_store.load();
```

When I switch NestedList to root card, it will contain mixed data from previous configuration and current one:

```
App.views.hdTreeView.setActiveItem(0);
```

Question: How should I "clear/reset" NestedList before loading entirely new data (same data model)? Do I have to clear TreeStore / SubStores and Proxy as well, if yes, how? Maybe using destroy() method and recreate new components?

If I remove all lists using removeAll() and than reload store, new list will not be created.

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried kind of dirty solution: after loading new data, I invoke `onBackTap()` for as long as there is only one item left in this collection: `App.views.hdTreeView.items`

Answer (score 1):

```
 showDetail: function(list, index , element , record) {
            //Take your store
            var store = Ext.getStore('yourstore');

            //Apply the params
            Ext.apply(store.getProxy()._extraParams, {
                id : record.data.id
            });

            //Reload your store
            store.load();
}
```

put this code at controller

just change `extraParams` to fetch new data.

in store dont input `exterparam`.

so u cab use just one url but chnage just param for fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

First use `store.setProxy()` and pass new proxy object then use this:

`nestedListObject.bindStore(store.load());`

where the `nestedListObject` is your nested list.

Comment: sorry, but NestedList does not have bindStore() method. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Will actually creating new proxy object be different from changing the URL? Anyway, I use my loop to go back to root list `while(HdMobile.views.hdTreeView.items.length > 1){
App.views.hdTreeView.onBackTap();}`

Comment: As far as I understand, it's the TreeStore that actually keeps the old data not the proxy, so I could use a kind of "flush" method or is that handled by "clearOnLoad"? Will that remove all previously existing items or only subtree?

Comment: Just to clarify: bindStore() method is available only in Ext.List not NestedList. Unfortunately even creating new store and new proxy and using Load() will not reload NestedList. NestedList does not fire Load event (I think this is a confirmed bug...)

Comment: I think that the problem is that the nestedlist doesn't 'repaint' itself. So even though you have no elements in the store or the elements changed, the actual HTML isn't updated. I'm bit confused about your loop with the root list etc. I can't understand what you want to do with that, but anyway I think that is best to just destroy the old list and create a new one with the updated store.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't get the list to recreate after store load. The only thing that worked for me, was to change the URL and call Load on an existing Store and Proxy (I could also replace proxy as suggested by you with the same result). When you navigate deeper into the list and than try to change reload store with new data, you end up with two problems: one was collection of old lists visible under debugger, two: a back button linked to one of those old lists. My loop removed old lists and goes to root list. I have tried removeAll method but it destroys the list

Comment: Why you couldn't recreate it? Can you provide some code, preferably on jsfiddle so I can edit it? Do you use ST1.1 or ST2?

Comment: It's ST1.1, I will most likely update to ST2 or go native, as working with buggy framework is't fun. Performance seems to be a problem as well. You have said "I think that the problem is that the nestedlist doesn't 'repaint' itself" - so that's my problem but using componentDoLayout() doesn't help.

Comment: Not buggy? So why do I have to use fixes for: 1) Xml attributes reading - Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR, 2) Programmatic List selection change fails until list is shown, 3) defaultRootId parameter is not honored in TreeStore 4) data store getById not working correctly, just to name a few. (Just one of the comments from Sencha Dev: "Seems we have a bug in that functionality, niktw's patch above should address this for you until we put out a new release"